# Question about Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

It is my understanding that a 95% confidence interval means that after many repeated experiments, there is an **exact** probability that 95% of the experiments **will** capture the true value.

So for 100 experiments, 95 of the experiments will capture the true value. However, for each individual experiment, there is only a 50% chance of capturing the true value because each sample either captures the true value or doesn't.

My questions are:

1. Is the probability exact? Not approximately 95% but exact?
2. How many repeated experiments are needed? For example, does 20 repeated experiments also result in exactly 19 experiments capturing the true value? Is there a possibility that all 20 repeated experiments will end up capturing the true value? Does this 95% probability only apply to very large repetitions like 100 or 1000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 100 experiments you will not get exactly 95% of CIs to contain the true value, sometimes it will be less, sometimes more, in the same way, as when you do two coinflips, you will not get always 1 head and 1 tail.

If you mean exact in a statistical way that 95% of infinite repetitions of the same sampling procedure will give you CIs that contain the true parameter then that is the definition of the CI so by definition yes. In practice, you might not get close to this number, because some procedures to construct confidence intervals are approximate, and the confidence intervals also depend on the model assumptions. E.g., normality, independent random samples and so on.

Each individual CI does not have 50% chance of either yes or no, in the same way how you don't have a 50% chance to win a lottery, either you win or you don't. Statisticians sometimes say that, and it is really annoying and does not help anybody. What they want to say, is that strictly speaking the 95% is defined for many repetitions, but not for a single interval, so (in their view) it's not meaningful to talk about the probability of a parameter to be in one specific or sometimes called realized interval unless you convert to bayesianism.

Here is an example why 95% of all intervals containing the true value does not imply that a specific interval has a 95% chance to contain the true value. If I report 95% of the times that an interval is from -infinity to infinity, and 5% that the interval is empty, this procedure will correctly contain the true value 95% of the times, but if I look at the interval -inf to inf I know that it has 100% chance of capturing the true value. This is however not how confidence intervals are usually constructed and in practice, the difference between long-running frequencies and individual probabilities is just a needless pedantry (although many people smarter than me will disagree, they are also bigger pedants)

Comment: Actually exactly 95 of the 100 experiments may, in fact, contain a "true parameter". But you're right, the issue boils down to little more than a frequentist understanding of probability.